# How to get native browser cookie from an android application

Tags: android, cookies, http-get

I'm developing a web site and an android application in which
1) the end user access my web site from the android native browser and set the unique id as a cookie.
2)When starting the application, it checks the native browser cookie and decides the registerd user or not.

The question is how to implement the way to get the browser cookie.

Comment: The following can be the solution?
-Invoke the browser from the application, read the cookie and redirect to the appliction with parameter(the cookie read)

Comment: I also tried the httpget and httpresponse in api. But it doesn't work.